# Iphone Core data - automatic saving or not?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I started using core data and I read that I can save the data using the managedObjectContext "save" function.

However, I noticed that when I fetch records from my store (sqlite db), even if I change my managed object without saving, and I reload my view , the new data is loaded.
(In my viewWillAppear I fetch the data all over again from the store).

So if there some automatic saving going on under the hood ? and if that's the case when should I use the "save" function.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifications are maintained in-memory for the life of your application.  `Save` commits outstanding changes to the persistent store.  You must save for changes to persist between app launches.  Explicitly calling `save` allows you to reduce memory consumption, distribute disk writes, and verify the integrity of your data.  All of this comes at the expense of a trip to your persistent store.